# calc() in less doesn't work

Tags: css, less

I want a div has a right margin depending of the screen width.
I wrote the following CSS rule:

```
...{
   right: calc(100% - 960px);
}
```

But I see in the following result in firebug:

```
right: calc(-860%) !important;
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: kindly provide me view on jsfiddle then we can help you out easily

Comment: Do you get the same issue in other browsers?

Comment: Make sure you have a space between "100%" "-" and "960px" in your code. Like your example.

Comment: try with this code " right: calc(100% - 960px); " if it dont work let us know in which browser you are facing issue.

Comment: I get this error in Chrome 48, IE 11 and Mozilla Firefox 44.

Comment: I'm unable to replicate this in Chrome 48 on Windows using Chrome's built-in development tools to view the computed value.

Comment: The problem is that takes 100% like 100 for the sum and not like the 100% of the width

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Also, that's not a `margin`...it's positioning.

Answer (score 1):

My problem was using less instead of css. I resolved doing

```
right: calc(~"100% - 960px");
```

Answer (score -1):

Please define the width of your div 
Like

```
div {  
  width: 90%; /* fallback if needed */  
  width: calc(100% - 3em);
}
```

Comment: Why would changing from px to em fix it?

Comment: The father's div has width: 100%;